# Drawing of sharingan and rinnegan eyes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I like the Naruto Shippuden anime. I want to draw the sharingan and rinnegan eyes using the TikZ package, but I'm having trouble determining the coordinates. Approximately like this image.
[image]
and this
[image]
Here is the MWE code I created.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{lightmauve}{rgb}{0.86, 0.82, 1.0}
\definecolor{red(ncs)}{rgb}{0.77, 0.01, 0.2}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{metallicRed}{RGB}{135,22,20}
\definecolor{metallicBlue}{RGB}{44, 88, 128}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[
left color = red(ncs),
right color = red(ncs),
middle color = red!60,
shading angle = 135
]   (0,0) circle (1.5);
\draw [line width=2pt] (0,0) circle (1.5);
\draw [line width=1.7pt] (0,0) circle (1);
\filldraw (0,0) circle (5pt);
\filldraw (-1,0) circle (4pt);
\filldraw (.5,.85) circle (4pt);
\filldraw (.5,-.85) circle (4pt);
\filldraw (-1,-0.15) -- (-1.3,0) -- (-1,0);
     
\hspace{4cm}
\shade[
left color = lightmauve,
right color = lightmauve,
middle color = white!40,
shading angle = -135
]   (0,0) circle (1.5);
\draw (0,0) circle (1.5);
\draw (0,0) circle (1.2);
\draw (0,0) circle (.9);
\draw (0,0) circle (.6);
\filldraw [lightmauve](0,0) circle (.3);
\filldraw (0,0) circle (.15);
\end{tikzpicture}

\hspace{0.7cm}Sharingan \hspace{2.5cm} Rinnegan
\end{document}
```

Can see in the drawing of the sharingan eye, the lines on the circle are not correct and I also want the Rinnegan eye to be slightly oval in shape like the picture in the Naruto Shippuden anime.
Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Please don't delete and repost your questions.

Comment: Yes sir. I wrote the wrong code earlier.

Comment: Maybe you could add a picture of the intended output to clarify the question.

Answer (score 5):

The first one is pretty simple. Here is an approach:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {fadings}

\tikzfading[name=my fade,inner color=transparent!0,outer color=transparent!40]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\fill[red,path fading=my fade] (0,0) circle (3);
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2);
\fill (0,0) circle (0.3);
\foreach\i in {80,200,320}
  \fill[rotate=\i] (2,0) ++ (-30:0.2) arc (330:90:0.2) arc (90:-60:0.3) to[out=60,in=-30] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update 2:** A little explanation for the first eye (following Dr. Manuel Kuehner's comment).
Let's take a look at the fragment:

```
\fill[rotate=\i] (2,0) ++ (-30:0.2) arc (330:90:0.2) arc (90:-60:0.3) to[out=60,in=-30] cycle;
```

It first rotates the canvas an angle `\i` (specified in the line before), then chooses the (rotated) point (2,0) over the black circle (the point O in the following figure) and moves 0.2cm with an -30 degrees angle to a new point A. Form there it draws an arc (in red) starting at said -30 angle and ending at 90 degrees (B) with radius 0.2cm. Then it draws a new arc (in blue) from (B), starting at 90 degrees and ending at -60 (point C), now with radius 0.3cm. And last, it connects both arcs with a curve that starts at (C) with 60 degrees and ends at A with -30 degrees.

[image]

**Update 1:** And the second one, using `clip`, `even odd rule`, and a macro for the eye contour line that will be used a few times.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {fadings}

\definecolor{eyecolor}{HTML}{C7B7D1}%
\newcommand{\eye}
{
  (-10.3,-4.6) to[out=5,  in=180] (0,-4.4)
               to[out=0,  in=250,looseness=1.2] (10.6,4)
               to[out=160,in=55 ,looseness=1.2] cycle;
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
\fill[eyecolor]\eye;
\fill (0,0) circle (0.4);
\begin{scope}
  \clip\eye;
  \foreach\i in {1.3,2.7,4.1,5.8,7.3,8.9,10.5}
    \draw (0,0) circle (\i);
  \fill[gray,fill opacity=0.8,shift={(-0.4,-0.5)},even odd rule] (-12,-6) rectangle (12,6) \eye;
\end{scope}
\fill[even odd rule] (-12,-6) rectangle (12,6) \eye;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: I am impressed how little code is needed!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you created the three "weird" objects (circles with hook)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, see my edit, I hope it's clear enough (my English is not so good, you know...)

Comment: Thank you Mr. @JuanCastaño

Comment: Oh wow, that is quite an update! Great!